# Корректный поиск китайских и польских писем imap

Tags: delphi, email, imap, delphi-xe, pop3

```pascal
var
MSG_COUNT: Integer;
SearchInfo: array of TIdIMAP4SearchRec;
begin
  createImap;
  SetLength(SearchInfo, 1);
  Imap.SelectMailBox('INBOX');
  SearchInfo[0].SearchKey := skFrom;
  SearchInfo[0].Text :='@google.com';
  Imap.SearchMailBox(SearchInfo);
ShowMessage(High(Imap.MailBox.SearchResult).ToString);
end;
```

пытался устанавливать charset big5 и много что еще, так и не пойму можно ли как-то кроме как скачать в TidMessage проверить тело письма или заголовок адекватно? Пока трудности возникли исключительно с Польшей и Китаем

Пример:

```pascal
Imap.Host:='imap.189.cn';
Imap.Port:=993;
Imap.ConnectTimeout:=5000;
Imap.Username:='18960910370@189.cn';
Imap.Password:='zjc19930220.';

ищем вот так 
Imap.SelectMailBox('INBOX');
SearchInfo[0].SearchKey := skFrom;
SearchInfo[0].Text :='@epicgames.com';

показывает что нашел 183 письма в письмах это

From: =?UTF-8?B?57O757uf566h55CG5ZGY?=<Postmaster@189.cn>
TO:<18960910370@189.cn>
Subject: =?UTF-8?B?57O757uf6YCA5L+h?=
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed
Content-type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
```

Comment: Приведите в вопросе конкретный пример, пожалуйста. Как именно вы сейчас парсите и что, и как рузельтат вышлядит в почте и у вас, в чем отличия.

Comment: парсинг указан в коде, но при выводе заголовков в мемо, там вообще не то что нужно, там нормальная кодировка, но почему-то внутренний поиск ведется криво и всегда находит одинаковое количество писем для всех запросов

Comment: Приведите в вопросе конкретный пример, пожалуйста. Без примера, помочь вам затруднительно.

Comment: ```Imap.Host:='imap.189.cn';
Imap.Port:=993;
Imap.ConnectTimeout:=5000;
Imap.Username:='18960910370@189.cn';
Imap.Password:='zjc19930220.';

ищем вот так

Imap.SelectMailBox('INBOX');
  SearchInfo[0].SearchKey := skFrom;
  SearchInfo[0].Text :='@epicgames.com';

показывает что нашел 183 письма

в письмах это

From: =?UTF-8?B?57O757uf566h55CG5ZGY?=<Postmaster@189.cn>
TO:<18960910370@189.cn>
Subject: =?UTF-8?B?57O757uf6YCA5L+h?=        
MIME-Version: 1.0
     Content-Type: multipart/mixed
Content-type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64```

Comment: Кнопка "править" под вопросом .. ;-)

Comment: @Kromster исправил, но вопрос все равно остается актуальным